# how to understand such generic code of netty?

Tags: java, generics

I'm a newbie of Java and now study netty recently.

some generic class code make me puzzled. such like this:

```
package io.netty.util;

/**
 * A singleton which is safe to compare via the {@code ==} operator. Created and managed by {@link ConstantPool}.
 */
public interface Constant<T extends Constant<T>> extends Comparable<T> {

    /**
     * Returns the unique number assigned to this {@link Constant}.
     */
    int id();

    /**
     * Returns the name of this {@link Constant}.
     */
    String name();
}
```

the Constant's generic definition is the sub-class of self， that makes me feel like a loop-reference. what the purpose of such code?

bow

Comment: this is an interface which doesn't contain (implementation) code. What are you trying to understand? the Generics? They just make it possible for this interface to be used with more than one type

Comment: @Stultuske Could you explain why `T extends Constant<T>` was used instead of just `T`. I think this could be one thing that the OP does not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designer of this interface wants the actual implementation implement `Comparable`, hence the piece of code `extends Comparable<T>`. But not to compare any object, but rather to compare other instances of the **same** Constant.

So `T` in this context represents the actual type that implements `Constant`.

If you want to implement it, you must write something like:

```
public class MyConstant implements Constant<MyConstant> {

    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyConstant myConstant) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The constraint on `T` forces the implementation to provide a method `compareTo(MyConstant myConstant)`.

There is [a nice tutorial](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=136394) on this topic.